# Advanced JS Bundling - What to include/exclude

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, javascript, requirejs, jsbundling

So, I've been doing an advanced js bundling for my website and I've read a lot of information about it. I've decided to use m2 dev tools to help me do it, however, I've some doubts with the result I got. I won't post all my code here because it is a lot, but I'll post 2/3 bundles to see if someone is able to help me understand if I'm doing things right or wrong.

```
"modules": [
        {
            // Modules used on > 1 page(s) of the store
            "name": "bundles/shared",
            "include": [
                "jquery",
                "Magento_Theme/js/theme",
                "jquery/jquery-migrate",
                "jquery/patches/jquery",
                "jquery/jquery.mobile.custom",
                "owl.carousel/owl.carousel.min",
                "Smartwave_Megamenu/js/sw_megamenu",
                "jquery-ui-modules/widget",
                "jquery/jquery.cookie",
                "jquery-ui-modules/core",
                "jquery-ui-modules/accordion",
                "domReady",
                "jquery-ui-modules/button",
                "jquery-ui-modules/datepicker",
                "jquery-ui-modules/effect",
                "jquery-ui-modules/effect-blind",
                "jquery-ui-modules/effect-bounce",
                "jquery-ui-modules/effect-clip",
                "jquery-ui-modules/effect-drop",
                "jquery-ui-modules/effect-explode",
                "jquery-ui-modules/effect-fade",
                "jquery-ui-modules/effect-fold",
                "jquery-ui-modules/effect-highlight",
                "jquery-ui-modules/effect-scale",
                "jquery-ui-modules/effect-pulsate",
                "jquery-ui-modules/effect-shake",
                "jquery-ui-modules/effect-slide",
                "jquery-ui-modules/effect-transfer",
                "jquery-ui-modules/mouse",
                "jquery-ui-modules/draggable",
                "jquery-ui-modules/droppable",
                "jquery-ui-modules/position",
                "jquery-ui-modules/menu",
                "jquery-ui-modules/autocomplete",
                "jquery-ui-modules/progressbar",
                "jquery-ui-modules/resizable",
                "jquery-ui-modules/dialog",
                "jquery-ui-modules/selectable",
                "jquery-ui-modules/slider",
                "jquery-ui-modules/sortable",
                "jquery-ui-modules/spinner",
                "jquery-ui-modules/tabs",
                "jquery-ui-modules/timepicker",
                "jquery-ui-modules/tooltip",
                "jquery/compat",
                "underscore",
                "mage/template",
                "mage/smart-keyboard-handler",
                "knockoutjs/knockout",
                "knockoutjs/knockout-es5",
                "mage/ie-class-fixer",
                "js/jquery.stellar.min",
                "matchMedia",
                "js/jquery.lazyload",
                "moment",
                "mage/apply/scripts",
                "mage/apply/main",
                "mage/mage",
                "mage/translate",
                "mage/translate-inline",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/extender/observable_array",
                "jquery/jquery-storageapi",
                "mage/collapsible",
                "mage/tabs",
                "text!ui/template/modal/modal-slide.html",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/key-codes",
                "text!ui/template/modal/modal-popup.html",
                "text!ui/template/modal/modal-custom.html",
                "Magento_Ui/js/modal/modal",
                "Magento_Ui/js/modal/confirm",
                "mage/dataPost",
                "jquery/jquery.metadata",
                "jquery/validate",
                "mage/validation",
                "text!js-translation.json",
                "knockoutjs/knockout-repeat",
                "knockoutjs/knockout-fast-foreach",
                "mage/utils/wrapper",
                "es6-collections",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/events",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/extender/bound-nodes",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/mage-init",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/fadeVisible",
                "text!ui/template/tooltip/tooltip.html",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/registry/registry",
                "mage/calendar",
                "spectrum",
                "tinycolor",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/loader",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/renderer",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/i18n",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/keyboard",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/range",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/after-render",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/autoselect",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/outer_click",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/staticChecked",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/simple-checked",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/collapsible",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/bind-html",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/tooltip",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/color-picker",
                "domReady!",
                "Magento_Theme/js/responsive",
                "mage/common",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/message-pool",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/levels-pool",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/logger",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/console-output-handler",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/logger-utils",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/view/utils/bindings",
                "mage/utils/objects",
                "mage/utils/compare",
                "mage/utils/strings",
                "mage/utils/arrays",
                "mage/utils/template",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/formatter",
                "FormData",
                "mage/utils/misc",
                "mage/utils/main",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/optgroup",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/datepicker",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/class",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/observable_source",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/storage/local",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/entry",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/entry-factory",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/logger/console-logger",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/template/engine",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/scope",
                "MutationObserver",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/view/utils/dom-observer",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/view/utils/async",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/resizable",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bindings/bootstrap",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/knockout/bootstrap",
                "mage/bootstrap",
                "mage/loader",
                "mage/dropdowns",
                "mage/dropdown",
                "Magento_Search/js/form-mini",
                "Mirasvit_Event/js/capture",
                "mage/validation/validation",
                "mage/cookies",
                "Magento_PageCache/js/page-cache",
                "Magento_Cookie/js/notices",
                "Magento_Ui/js/block-loader",
                "Magento_Customer/js/section-config",
                "Bss_AjaxCart/js/jquery.fancybox",
                "text!ui/template/block-loader.html",
                "Bss_PreOrder/js/catalog-add-to-cart",
                "Magento_Persistent/js/view/customer-data-mixin",
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/renderer/types",
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/renderer/layout",
                "Magento_Ui/js/core/app",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/element/links",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/element/element",
                "mage/url",
                "mage/storage",
                "Magento_Customer/js/customer-data",
                "Bss_AjaxCart/js/ajax",
                "Magento_Customer/js/invalidation-processor",
                "Magento_Catalog/js/product/view/product-ids",
                "Magento_Catalog/js/product/view/product-ids-resolver",
                "Magento_Catalog/js/catalog-add-to-cart",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/core/collection",
                "Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals",
                "Magento_Msrp/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals",
                "Magento_Catalog/js/view/image",
                "Magento_Wishlist/js/view/wishlist",
                "Magento_Customer/js/view/customer",
                "MageWorx_SearchSuiteAutocomplete/js/autocomplete",
                "MageWorx_SearchSuiteAutocomplete/js/bindEvents",
                "MageWorx_SearchSuiteAutocomplete/js/dataProvider",
                "Magento_Theme/js/view/messages",
                "Magento_Customer/js/invalidation-rules/website-rule",
                "mage/decorate",
                "Magento_Catalog/js/view/compare-products",
                "Magento_Customer/js/model/authentication-popup",
                "Magento_Ui/js/modal/alert",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/sidebar",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/minicart",
                "MSP_ReCaptcha/js/registry",
                "MSP_ReCaptcha/js/reCaptcha",
                "Magento_Captcha/js/model/captchaList",
                "MSP_ReCaptcha/js/ui-messages-mixin",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/spinner",
                "mage/requirejs/resolver",
                "Magento_Catalog/js/product/storage/ids-storage",
                "Magento_Catalog/js/product/storage/ids-storage-compare",
                "Magento_Captcha/js/action/refresh",
                "Magento_Captcha/js/model/captcha",
                "Magento_Captcha/js/view/checkout/defaultCaptcha",
                "Magento_Catalog/js/product/query-builder",
                "Magento_Catalog/js/product/storage/data-storage",
                "Magento_Catalog/js/product/storage/storage-service",
                "Magento_Catalog/js/storage-manager",
                "text!MageWorx_SearchSuiteAutocomplete/template/autocomplete.html",
                "Magento_Ui/js/model/messages",
                "Magento_Ui/js/model/messageList",
                "Magento_Customer/js/action/login",
                "Magento_Captcha/js/view/checkout/loginCaptcha",
                "Magento_Ui/js/view/messages",
                "text!Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/content.html",
                "Magento_Ui/js/form/adapter/buttons",
                "Magento_Ui/js/form/adapter",
                "Magento_Ui/js/form/form",
                "Magento_Customer/js/view/authentication-popup",
                "text!ui/template/collection.html",
                "text!Magento_Customer/template/authentication-popup.html",
                "text!Magento_Ui/template/messages.html",
                "text!MSP_ReCaptcha/template/reCaptcha.html",
                "text!Magento_Captcha/template/checkout/captcha.html",
                "Magento_Cookie/js/require-cookie",
                "Magento_Wishlist/js/add-to-wishlist",
                "Magento_Sales/js/view/last-ordered-items",
                "Magento_Catalog/js/price-utils",
                "text!Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/default.html",
                "text!Magento_Catalog/template/product/image_with_borders.html",
                "text!Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/item/price.html",
                "text!Magento_Checkout/template/minicart/subtotal.html",
                "text!Magento_Tax/template/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals.html",
                "mage/trim-input",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/quote",
                "Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/shipping_method/price",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/totals",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-data",
                "MageWorx_ShippingRules/js/checkout/model/shipping-rates-validation-rules-mixin",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rates-validation-rules",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-method",
                "MageWorx_ShippingRules/js/checkout/model/shipping-rates-validation-rules/general",
                "MageWorx_ShippingRules/js/checkout/model/shipping-rates-validator/general",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/step-navigator",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/abstract-total",
                "Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/subtotal",
                "Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/grand-total",
                "Magento_Weee/js/view/checkout/summary/weee",
                "Magento_SalesRule/js/view/summary/discount",
                "Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/tax",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-address/form-popup-state",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-shipping-address",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/default-post-code-resolver",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/postcode-validator",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/shipping",
                "Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/shipping",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/error-processor",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/action/select-billing-address",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/new-customer-address",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/address-converter",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-billing-address",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/default-validation-rules",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/default-validator",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rates-validator",
                "MageWorx_ShippingRules/js/checkout/view/shipping-rates-validation/general",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/utils",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/rules",
                "Magento_Ui/js/lib/validation/validator",
                "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/abstract",
                "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/select",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/url-builder",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-list",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/full-screen-loader",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-rate-registry",
                "Magento_Customer/js/model/customer/address",
                "Magento_Customer/js/model/customer-addresses",
                "Magento_Customer/js/model/address-list",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/action/create-shipping-address",
                "Magento_Customer/js/model/customer",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/resource-url-manager",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-totals",
                "MagestyApps_FixRules/js/action/select-payment-method",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment-service",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/checkout-data-resolver",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-service",
                "text!Magento_Tax/template/checkout/summary/subtotal.html",
                "text!ui/template/form/element/select.html",
                "text!Magento_Tax/template/checkout/shipping_method/price.html"
            ],
            "exclude": [],
            "create": true
        },
        {
            "name": "bundles/customer-account-index",
            "create": true,
            "include": [
                "mage/toggle"
            ],
            "exclude": [
                "bundles/shared"
            ]
        },
        {
            "name": "bundles/checkout-index-index",
            "create": true,
            "include": [
                "Magento_Checkout/js/checkout-loader",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/thumbnail",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/view/review/addition",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/message",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/3columns-colspan.html",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/renderer-list",
                "Magento_OfflinePayments/js/view/payment/offline-payments",
                "Ifthenpay_Multibanco/js/view/payment/multibanco-payments",
                "Magento_Paypal/js/view/payment/paypal-payments",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/additional-validators",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/model/payment-service",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/model/paypal_express_compatible",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/model/osc-data",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/view/review/comment",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/model/compatible/amazon-pay",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/model/checkout-data-resolver",
                "Magento_Shipping/js/model/config",
                "Magento_Shipping/js/view/checkout/shipping/shipping-policy",
                "Magento_Ui/js/form/components/group",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/cart-items",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/totals",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details/subtotal",
                "Magento_Tax/js/view/checkout/summary/item/details/subtotal",
                "Magento_Weee/js/view/checkout/summary/item/price/weee",
                "Magento_Weee/js/view/checkout/summary/item/price/row_incl_tax",
                "Magento_Weee/js/view/checkout/summary/item/price/row_excl_tax",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/summary/item/details",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/model/braintree-paypal",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-converter",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/sidebar",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/sidebar",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/model/gift-message",
                "Magento_Customer/js/action/check-email-availability",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/list",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/view/geoip",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/customer-email-validator",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/email-validator",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/form/element/email",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/model/resource-url-manager",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/action/check-email-availability",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/view/form/element/email",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/action/gift-message-item",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/container/sidebar.html",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/model/address/type/google",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/model/address/auto-complete",
                "Mageplaza_DeliveryTime/js/model/delivery-information",
                "Mageplaza_DeliveryTime/js/action/set-shipping-information-mixin",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/estimation",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/action/get-payment-information",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/model/shipping-save-processor/checkout",
                "Magento_Ui/js/form/element/post-code",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/container/summary.html",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/container/review/addition.html",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/view/payment",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/list",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/view/payment/list",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/model/osc-loader",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/action/update-item",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/view/summary/item/details",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/action/payment-total-information",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/new-address-mixin",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/model/shipping-rate-processor/customer-address-mixin",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/model/shipping-rate-service",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/payload-extender",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor/default",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/shipping-save-processor",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/action/set-checkout-information",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/view/review/placeOrder",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-shipping-information",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/model/shipping-rates-validator",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/view/shipping",
                "text!Magento_Checkout/template/summary/totals.html",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/container/summary/cart-items.html",
                "text!Magento_Checkout/template/estimation.html",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/container/payment.html",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/payment-methods/list.html",
                "text!Magento_Tax/template/checkout/summary/shipping.html",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/payment/method-group",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/view/shipping-address/address-renderer/default",
                "text!Magento_Tax/template/checkout/summary/tax.html",
                "text!Magento_Tax/template/checkout/summary/grand-total.html",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/checkout/summary/weee.html",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/container/summary/item/details.html",
                "text!Magento_Checkout/template/payment-methods/list.html",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/container/shipping.html",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/container/review/place-order.html",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/container/address/shipping-address.html",
                "text!Magento_SalesRule/template/summary/discount.html",
                "text!Magento_Checkout/template/summary/item/details/thumbnail.html",
                "text!Magento_Tax/template/checkout/summary/item/details/subtotal.html",
                "text!Magento_Shipping/template/checkout/shipping/shipping-policy.html",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/container/address/shipping/form.html",
                "text!Magento_Checkout/template/shipping-address/list.html",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/container/review/comment.html",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/container/form/element/email.html",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/action/set-billing-address",
                "text!Magento_Weee/template/checkout/summary/item/price/row_excl_tax.html",
                "text!ui/template/group/group.html",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/container/form/field.html",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/container/address/shipping/address-renderer/default.html",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/billing-address-postcode-validator",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/billing-address",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/view/billing-address",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/container/form/element/input.html",
                "text!ui/template/form/element/helper/tooltip.html",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/action/redirect-on-success",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/action/place-order-mixins",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/container/address/billing-address.html",
                "text!Mageplaza_Osc/template/container/address/billing/checkbox.html",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/model/place-order",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/action/place-order",
                "Mageplaza_Osc/js/model/agreements-assigner",
                "Magento_CheckoutAgreements/js/model/place-order-mixin",
                "Magento_Checkout/js/view/payment/default",
                "Magento_OfflinePayments/js/view/payment/method-renderer/banktransfer-method",
                "Magento_OfflinePayments/js/view/payment/method-renderer/cashondelivery-method",
                "Magento_OfflinePayments/js/view/payment/method-renderer/checkmo-method",
                "text!Magento_Checkout/template/billing-address/list.html",
                "text!Magento_OfflinePayments/template/payment/banktransfer.html",
                "text!Magento_OfflinePayments/template/payment/cashondelivery.html",
                "text!Magento_OfflinePayments/template/payment/checkmo.html",
                "text!Magento_Checkout/template/payment/before-place-order.html"
            ],
            "exclude": [
                "bundles/shared"
            ]
        }
```

**"bundles/customer-account-index"**, What is happening here? The m2 dev tools tells me I should include "mage/toggle" and exclude "bundles/shared". From what I've understand, it will only include 1 dependency? All my bundles are excluding only the "bundles/shared", is it supposed to be like this? Shouldn't it exclude the other bundles aswell? Or shouldn't it exclude other bundles and include the "bundles/shared", since it is the "shared"?

Comment: I hope you have successfully finished JS bundling part.